# Rails 4 Customize ActiveAdmin batch action collection form labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin, batch-processing, label

I am using on Rails 4 and ActiveAdmin, a batch action collection form to capture input from the user as they perform a batch action ( in this case a batch mailer). Is there a way to customize the labels for the inputs?

Say for example:

```
    batch_action :email, priority: 1 , form: {main_subject: :text,
                                              message: :textarea
                                             } do |ids, inputs|
  batch_action_collection.find(ids).each do |user|
   ContactBatchMailer.contact_batch_email(main_subject, message,...


    Instead of having "main_subject", I would like to display a better formatted text, like "Main Subject", or even better, something more descriptive than the variable name by itself.
```

I dug in the documentation https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/9-batch-actions.md#batch-action-forms but I was not able to. 
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is rendered by modal_dialog.js.coffee, it should be possible to override and customize, for example see this [declined pull request](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3965/files) from @mmustala

Comment: Thank you, Piers C!

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to use a symbol for the form input name. A string will also work. So in your case you could do:

```
batch_action :email, priority: 1 , form: {'Main Subject': :text,
                                             message: :textarea
                                            } do |ids, inputs|
    main_s = inputs['Main Subject']
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a life saver!